# python Converting and solving of stiff ODE system

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have stiff system of differential equations given to the first-order ODE. This system is written in Maple. The default method used by Maple is the Rosenbrock method. Now my task is to solve these equations with python tools.

1) I do not know how to write the equations in the python code.

2) I do not know how to solve the equations with numpy, scipy, matplotlib or PyDSTool. For the library PyDSTool I did not find any examples at all, although I read that it is well suited for stiff systems.

Code:

```
import numpy
import scipy
import matplotlib

varepsilon = pow(10, -2); j = -2.5*pow(10, -2); e = 3.0; tau = 0.3; delta = 2.0

u0 = -math.sqrt(-1 + math.sqrt(varepsilon ** 2 + 12) / varepsilon) * math.sqrt(2) / 6
u = -math.sqrt(-1 + math.sqrt(varepsilon ** 2 + 12) / varepsilon) * math.sqrt(2) * (1 + delta) / 6
v = 1 / (1 - 2 / e) * math.sqrt(j ** 2 + (1 - 2 / e) * (e ** 2 * u ** 2 + 1))

y8 = lambda y1,y5,y7: 1 / (1 - 2 / y1) * math.sqrt(y5 ** 2 + (1 - 2 / y1) * (1 + y1 ** 2 * y7 ** 2))
E0 = lambda y1,y8: (1 - 2 / y1) * y8
Phi0 = lambda y1,y7: y1 ** 2 * y7


y08 = y8(y1=e, y5=j, y7=u0);
E = E0(y1=e, y8=y08); Phi = Phi0(y1=e, y7=u0)
# initial values
z01 = e; z03 = 0; z04 = 0; z05 = j; z07 = u0; z08 = y08;

p1 = -z1(x)*z5(x)/(z1(x)-2);
p3 = -z1(x)^2*z7(x);
p4 = z8(x)*(1-2/z1(x));
Q1 = -z5(x)^2/(z1(x)*(z1(x)-2))+(z8(x)^2/z1(x)^3-z7(x)^2)*(z1(x)-2);
Q3 = 2*z5(x)*z7(x)/z1(x);
Q4 = 2*z5(x)*z8(x)/(z1(x)*(z1(x)-2));
c1 = z1(x)*z7(x)*varepsilon;
c3 = -z1(x)*z5(x)*varepsilon;
C = z7(x)*varepsilon/z1(x)-z8(x)*(1-2/z1(x));
d1 = -z1(x)*z8(x)*varepsilon;
d3 = z1(x)*z5(x)*varepsilon;
B = z1(x)^2*z7(x)-z8(x)*varepsilon*(1-2/z1(x));
Omega = 1/(c1*d3*p3+c3*d1*p4-c3*d3*p1);

# differential equations
diff(z1(x), x) = z5(x);
diff(z3(x), x) = z7(x);
diff(z4(x), x) = z8(x);
diff(z5(x), x) = Omega*(-Q1*c1*d3*p3 - Q1*c3*d1*p4 + Q1*c3*d3*p1 + B*c3*p4 + C*d3*p3 + E*d3*p3 - Phi*c3*p4);
diff(z7(x), x) = -Omega*(Q3*c1*d3*p3 + Q3*c3*d1*p4 - Q3*c3*d3*p1 + B*c1*p4 - C*d1*p4 + C*d3*p1 - E*d1*p4 + E*d3*p1 - Phi*c1*p4);
diff(z8(x), x) = Omega*(-Q4*c1*d3*p3 - Q4*c3*d1*p4 + Q4*c3*d3*p1 + B*c1*p3 - B*c3*p1 - C*d1*p3 - E*d1*p3 - Phi*c1*p3 + Phi*c3*p1);

#features to be found and built curve
{z1(x), z3(x), z4(x), z5(x), z7(x), z8(x)}
```

Answer (score 0):

After drifting on the Internet, I found something in principle:

```
import math

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

from mpmath import mp, mpf
mp.dps = 50


varepsilon = pow(10, -2); j = 2.5*pow(10, -4); e = 3.0; tau = 0.5; delta = 2.0

u0 = -math.sqrt(-1 + math.sqrt(varepsilon ** 2 + 12) / varepsilon) * math.sqrt(2) / 6
u = -math.sqrt(-1 + math.sqrt(varepsilon ** 2 + 12) / varepsilon) * math.sqrt(2) * (1 + delta) / 6
v = 1 / (1 - 2 / e) * math.sqrt(j ** 2 + (1 - 2 / e) * (e ** 2 * u ** 2 + 1))

y8 = lambda y1,y5,y7: 1 / (1 - 2 / y1) * math.sqrt(y5 ** 2 + (1 - 2 / y1) * (1 + y1 ** 2 * y7 ** 2))
E0 = lambda y1,y8: (1 - 2 / y1) * y8
Phi0 = lambda y1,y7: y1 ** 2 * y7


y08 = y8(y1=e, y5=j, y7=u0);
E = E0(y1=e, y8=y08); Phi = Phi0(y1=e, y7=u0)
# initial values
z01 = e; z03 = 0.0; z04 = 0.0; z05 = j; z07 = u0; z08 = y08;

def model(x, z, varepsilon, E, Phi):

    z1, z3, z4, z5, z7, z8 = z[0], z[1], z[2], z[3], z[4], z[5]

    p1 = -z1*z5/(z1 - 2);
    p3 = -pow(z1, 2) *z7;
    p4 = z8*(1 - 2/z1);
    Q1 = -pow(z5, 2)/(z1*(z1 - 2)) + (pow(z8, 2)/pow(z1, 3) - pow(z7, 2))*(z1 - 2);
    Q3 = 2*z5*z7/z1;
    Q4 = 2*z5*z8/(z1*(z1 - 2));
    c1 = z1*z7*varepsilon;
    c3 = -z1*z5*varepsilon;
    C = z7*varepsilon/z1 - z8*(1 - 2/z1);
    d1 = -z1*z8*varepsilon;
    d3 = z1*z5*varepsilon;
    B = pow(z1, 2)*z7 - z8*varepsilon*(1 - 2/z1);
    Omega = 1/(c1*d3*p3+c3*d1*p4-c3*d3*p1);

    # differential equations
    dz1dx = z5;
    dz3dx  = z7;
    dz4dx  = z8;
    dz5dx  = Omega*(-Q1*c1*d3*p3 - Q1*c3*d1*p4 + Q1*c3*d3*p1 + B*c3*p4 + C*d3*p3 + E*d3*p3 - Phi*c3*p4);
    dz7dx  = -Omega*(Q3*c1*d3*p3 + Q3*c3*d1*p4 - Q3*c3*d3*p1 + B*c1*p4 - C*d1*p4 + C*d3*p1 - E*d1*p4 + E*d3*p1 - Phi*c1*p4);
    dz8dx = Omega*(-Q4*c1*d3*p3 - Q4*c3*d1*p4 + Q4*c3*d3*p1 + B*c1*p3 - B*c3*p1 - C*d1*p3 - E*d1*p3 - Phi*c1*p3 + Phi*c3*p1);
    dzdx = [dz1dx, dz3dx, dz4dx, dz5dx, dz7dx, dz8dx]
    return dzdx

z0 = [z01, z03, z04, z05, z07, z08]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Start by specifying the integrator:
    # use ``vode`` with "backward differentiation formula"
    r = integrate.ode(model).set_integrator('vode', method='bdf')
    r.set_f_params(varepsilon, E, Phi)

    # Set the time range
    t_start = 0.0
    t_final = 0.1
    delta_t = 0.00001
    # Number of time steps: 1 extra for initial condition
    num_steps = np.floor((t_final - t_start)/delta_t) + 1

    r.set_initial_value(z0, t_start)

    t = np.zeros((int(num_steps), 1), dtype=np.float64)
    Z = np.zeros((int(num_steps), 6,), dtype=np.float64)
    t[0] = t_start
    Z[0] = z0


    k = 1
    while r.successful() and k < num_steps:
        r.integrate(r.t + delta_t)
        # Store the results to plot later
        t[k] = r.t
        Z[k] = r.y
        k += 1  

    # All done!  Plot the trajectories:
    Z1, Z3, Z4, Z5, Z7, Z8  = Z[:,0], Z[:,1] ,Z[:,2], Z[:,3], Z[:,4], Z[:,5]

    plt.plot(t,Z1,'r-',label=r'$r(s)$')
    plt.grid('on')
    plt.ylabel(r'$r$')
    plt.xlabel('proper time s')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()

    plt.plot(t,Z5,'r-',label=r'$\frac{dr}{ds}$')
    plt.grid('on')
    plt.ylabel(r'$\frac{dr}{ds}$')
    plt.xlabel('proper time s')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()


    plt.plot(t, Z7, 'r-', label=r'$\frac{dϕ}{ds}$')
    plt.grid('on')
    plt.xlabel('proper time s')
    plt.ylabel(r'$\frac{dϕ}{ds}$')
    plt.legend(loc='upper center')
    plt.show()
```

However, reviewing the solutions obtained by the library scipy,
I encountered the problem of inconsistency of the solutions obtained by scipy and Maple. The essence of the problem is that the solutions are quickly oscillating and the Maple catches these oscillations with high precision using Rosenbrock's method. While Pythonn has problems with this using Backward Differentiation Methods:

```
r = integrate.ode(model).set_integrator('vode', method='bdf')
```

http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Backward_differentiation_formulas

I tried all the modes of integrating: **“vode” ; “zvode”; “lsoda” ; “dopri5” ; “dop853”** and I found that the best suited mode “vode” however, still does not meet my needs...
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html

So this method catches oscillations in the range j ~ 10^{-5}-10^{-3}..While the maple shows good results for any j.

I present the results obtained by scipy for j ~ 10^{-2}:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/estu0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTQVI.png)

and the results obtained by Maple for j ~ 10^{-2}:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kccWI.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAH3t.jpg)

It is important that oscillations are physical solutions! That is, the Python badly captures oscillations for j ~ 10^{-2}((. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?? how to look at the absolute error of integration?